# Phonegap Blackberry Facebook share

Tags: blackberry, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the Childbrowser in Phonegap for Blackberry. Can I connect to Facebook and share through childbrowser? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use childbrowser for connecting to Facebbok and sharing on Facebook for Blackberry. Use childbrowser plugin for Blackberry and integrate using the source code provided in the link: https://github.com/DrewDahlman/phonegapFacebookApp .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to Facebook javascript SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/